# Linked Queue ADT implementation, Lost node

Tags: python, linked-list, garbage-collection, queue, adt

When I implemet the **dequeue()** method, and in the following code

```py
    def dequeue(self): 
        if self.is_empty(): 
            print("The Queue is empty")
            return
        answer = self._head._element 
#---------------------
        self._head = self._head._next #here, what happens with the "lost" node, because i think it is lost by the linked list
#---------------------
        self._size -= 1
        if self.is_empty():
            self._tail = None
        return answer
```

`Is that node retrieved by the garbage collector?`, because when i lost the reference to that node, and i have no way to access it.
The node is implemented as following within a LinkedList class.

```py
class _Node:
   __slots__ = "_element","_next"
   def __init__(self, element, next): 
       self._element = element 
       self._next = next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, it's a notation, and the garbage collector knows when to retrieve unused data.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).